# ajax/javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've narrowed down the possible errors to be within an if statement.  I'm trying to make two images appear within divs if my php file returns true after authenticating a user.  There error comes when I try to add the image to the divs "b1" and "b2" with "innerHTML."

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>
   <title> Incident Center </title>
   <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment/style/style.css">-->
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    ajaxRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
    ajaxRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            if(ajaxRequest.responseText=="true")
            {
            //ERROR HERE
            document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML ="<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>";
            document.getElementById('b2').innerHTML ="<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>";

            }

            else
            {
            document.getElementById('n1').innerHTML = "<h4>IT WAS FALSE</h4>";
            }
        }
    }
    var un = document.getElementById('un').value;
    var pw = document.getElementById('pw').value;
    var queryString = "?un=" + un + "&pw=" + pw;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "auth.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

    </script>
</head>

<body>


<div class="header">
Incident Center 

</div>



<p>


<div class="t1">
<form name='myForm'>
username: <input type='text' id='un'> <br>
password: <input type='password' id='pw'> <br>

<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Enter' />
</form>
</div>



</p>


<p>

<div id="n1">
<div id="b1"></div>
<div id="b2"></div>
</div>

</p>

</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with the quotes at this line

```
document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML ="<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>";
```

Try replacing it with this:

```
document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML ='<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have double quotes in your innerHTML value.

```
document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML ="<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>";
document.getElementById('b2').innerHTML ="<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>";
```

Change it to

```
document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML ='<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>';
document.getElementById('b2').innerHTML ='<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>';
```

Note the use of single quotes wrapping the strings you're trying to insert as they use " inside.

Similarly you could escape the quotes inside if you wanted to stick to using just double quotes although it seems pointless in this case. The escape character in javascript is a backslash . To further understand where you've gone wrong you can read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html which covers the topic well.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML ="<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>";
document.getElementById('b2').innerHTML ="<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>";
```

To:

```
document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML ='<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>';
document.getElementById('b2').innerHTML ='<img src="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment2/view.png" width=50 height=50>';
```